# How can I use the firebase --verbosity flag

Tags: firebase-tools

According to the release notes https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/cli there is a new --log-verbosity flag on the firebase cli that can be used to limit al the noise from the emulator. I can however not find any documentation on how to use this.

I have been looking in the code and there it seems the flag is --verbosity and I can see it can be set to DEBUG, INFO or QUIET.

I have tried

firebase emulators:start --log-verbosity:QUIET --only functions --inspect-functions

and

firebase emulators:start --verbosity:QUIET --only functions --inspect-functions

but i get error: unknown option '--log-verbosity:QUIET'

I am using firebase cli 12.7.0

How to can I limit all the outputs from the emulator so I can read my own logs